# Credit card fraud - record your face movement to unlock your account

Tags: credit-card, fraud

Recently I accessed my credit card account (with a well-known credit card company) and right on the web page received a message that my account is locked to "prevent some sort of fraud".

I called customer service and was instructed to process certain steps in order to unlock the account. A text message was sent to my phone with those instructions. After following mostly all of them (like verify your first and last name, email address, last 4 ssn...) I stumbled with the last step - video record of my face slow movement and submitting this video to the company back. I automatically rejected this step as I felt uncomfortable doing so. The customer service representative told me that I should get a mail with "different ways" to unlock the account.

I mean, what the video recording of my face has to do with verifying who I am and unlocking the account? When I initially opened the account I never provided "sample" of video.

Is this some sort of new way to verify who the person is?

Comment: Most likely they want to compare your picture to your photo id.  They would have you move slowly with video recording to make it easier to verify that someone didn't just find a picture of you and send it along.  The movement would also help because that would make it harder for someone to "photoshop" your face on themselves in a video.

Comment: someone from the credit card company is sitting and manually verifying government issued ID with the recording?

Comment: It's quite possible.  I'm not posting this as an answer because I'm not 100% sure myself.  This may help: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/191460/why-did-i-have-to-wave-my-hand-in-front-of-my-id-card